# Как Конкатенировать два отсортированных массива .?

Tags: javascript, c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arr = {12,13,22,1333 };
    int[] arr2 = {6,4,3596, };
    int[] vs = ArrayAdd(arr, arr2);

    Array.Sort(vs);
    foreach (var item in vs)
    {
        Console.Write(item+",");
    }
    //Console.WriteLine(vs.Length);
}
static T[] ArrayAdd<T>(T[] arr, T[] arr2)
{
    Sort1(arr);Sort1(arr2);
    var res = new T[arr.Length + arr2.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        res[i] = arr[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
        res[arr.Length + i] = arr2[i];
   
    return res;
}
```

как написать этот код, чтобы он работал на JavaScript. На выходе возвращает `undefined`, но на c# работает нормально

```
let arr=[7,3,6,1];
let arr2=[2,4,5];

let res = new Array(arr.length + arr2.length);

function merg(arr,arr2) {
    arr.sort();  arr2.sort();
  
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        res[i] = arr[i];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
        res[arr.Length + i] = arr2[i];
    return res;
};

console.log(merg(arr,arr2));
```

Comment: так результат этого кода не будет сортированным. Или вам и не надо сохранять массив сортированным?

Comment: я не понял вопроса. причём тут JS?

Comment: этот же код нужно написать на JS

Comment: @ԽաչատուրՄելքոնյան, покажи как ты его переписал на js, что он у тебя undefined возвращает

Comment: let arr=[7,3,6,1];
let arr2=[2,4,5];

   let res = new Array(arr.length + arr2.length);

function merg(arr,arr2) {
 
     arr.sort();  arr2.sort();
  
          for (let i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
               res[i] = arr[i];
           for (let i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
                res[arr.Length + i] = arr2[i];
           
            return res;
};

console.log(merg(arr,arr2));

Comment: @ԽաչատուրՄելքոնյան это бы в вопрос

Comment: @ԽաչատուրՄելքոնյան, добавь этот код прямо в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: @ԽաչատուրՄելքոնյան, проблема в опечатке: в одном месте ты правильно свойство `.length` используешь, а в других почему-то пишешь его с большой буквы

Comment: ОК спасибо @Grundy  но у меня проблема в том что когда в массиве есть двухзначние числа работает неправильно но а в c# е все нормално [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11]   c#  [1,11,2,3,4,5,6,7 ] js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код с c# переносится практически 1 к 1, если убрать из кода определение типов, и вызывать соответствующие методы, например, длину массива в js можно получить из свойства `.length`

Тогда из

```
static T[] ArrayAdd<T>(T[] arr, T[] arr2)
{
    Sort1(arr);Sort1(arr2);
    var res = new T[arr.Length + arr2.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        res[i] = arr[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.Length; i++)
        res[arr.Length + i] = arr2[i];
   
    return res;
}
```

Останется следующее

```
function ArrayAdd(arr, arr2)
{
    arr.sort();arr2.sort();
    var res = new Array(arr.length + arr2.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        res[i] = arr[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
        res[arr.length + i] = arr2[i];
   
    return res;
}
```

Единственное отличие в поведении теперь, заключается в том, что по умолчанию компаратор метода [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) сравнивает элементы как строки, в то время как в C# результат зависит от типа элементов коллекции.

Для правильной сортировки достаточно передать нужный компаратор:

```js
let arr = [7, 13, 6, 1];
let arr2 = [2, 4, 15];

function ArrayAdd(arr, arr2) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  arr2.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  var res = new Array(arr.length + arr2.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    res[i] = arr[i];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
    res[arr.length + i] = arr2[i];

  return res;
}
console.log(ArrayAdd(arr, arr2))
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: это решение  соотвествует этому  complexity O(n + m) ? и ест какое либо статя или учебник где внятно обесняют об этом time  complexity

Comment: @ԽաչատուրՄելքոնյան, сложность объединения - да, если не учитывать сложность сортировки